# Parsing an XML Element to Dataframe in scala

Tags: xml, scala, dataframe, element

I have an xml Response for a SOAP Request in Scala with Spark which i want to convert into a Dataframe so i can append it to a hive table.

I have tried databricks.spark.xml but it can only load xml files directly. I am unable to find a way to load an xml variable ( Elem)

Input:

```
    <XML>
    <hol_cal date="2019-01-01" Desc="New Year's Day"/>
    <hol_cal date="2019-04-19" Desc="Good Friday"/> 
    <hol_cal date="2019-04-22" Desc="Easter Monday"/>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </XML>
```

Output:
Data Frame:

|Date      |Desc          |
|2019-01-01|New Year's Day|
|2019-04-19|Good Friday   |
....

Comment: Can someone please help me with the same. I need to load the details from 2000 to till date. Thanks.

Comment: Did the solution I provided help?

Answer (score -1):

I would use the following method:

- Read the file into an RDD (where each element now consists of one row in the XML file)

```scala
val rawXML = sc.textFile(inputFileLocation)
```

- Create a case class schema like the following:

```scala
case class DateSchema(date: String, desc: String)
```

- Transform each row into an element of the DateSchema case class. You will probably want to filter out the rows that do not contain "date" and "Desc" strings in them first.

```scala
val parsedXML = rawXML.filter(row => row.contains("date") && row.contains("Desc")).map(row => {
   val splitRow = row.split("\"")
   DateSchema(splitRow(1), splitRow(3))
})
```

- Convert this RDD into a dataframe using .toDF

```scala
val dateDF = parsedXML.toDF
```

```scala
dateDF.show

+----------+--------------+
|      date|          desc|
+----------+--------------+
|2019-01-01|New Year's Day|
|2019-04-19|   Good Friday|
|2019-04-22| Easter Monday|
+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: he said he wants to create DF from Elem and not saved file.